# Need to remove the string chr and the % sign from the file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file which looks like below

```
chrM    152 165 45  21.43%
chrM    13811   324 70  17.77%
chr1    1669566 47  14  22.95%
chr1    1685929 144 33  18.64%
```

I want to remove the string `chr` and the `%` sign from the file. This is a `tab` delimited file. How should I use the `sed` command here?

my output should be :

```
M   152 165 45  21.43
M   13811   324 70  17.77
1   1669566 47  14  22.95
1   1685929 144 33  18.64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use sed or perl.

```
sed 's/^chr\|%$//g' file
```

Since basic sed uses BRE(*Basic Regular expression*), regex OR operator is denoted by `\|`.

Through perl.

```
perl -pe  's/^chr|%$//g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `%` is the last character on the line, this is simple in sed:

```
sed 's/^chr//; s/%$//' file
```

The first command removes `chr` from the start of the line and the second removes `%` from the end.

You can also combine the two commands if you like using the OR operator:

```
sed 's/^chr\|%$//g'
```

The matches either of the two patterns - in this case we also need the global modifier `g` so that both modifications can be made to the same line. The `|` operator is escaped using a `\`.

To edit the file in place, you can use the `-i` switch if you have it, or do the standard trick:

```
sed 's/^chr\|%$//g' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```